# jquery to slide down - up the form- hidden by default for the first time,

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
<div><input type="button" id="changePwd" value="Change your password"/></div>
<br/>
<div id="form_pwd">          
    <form method="POST" action="google.com" id="pwdChange">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="175px"><label for="oldPwd">Enter your password</label></td>                
                <td><input type="password" name="newPwd" id="newPwd" size="35"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="oldPwd_>"Re-enter your password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="newPwd_" id="newPwd_" size="35"/></td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Save Password" /></td>
    </tr>
        </table><br/>

    </form>
</div>

<script>
$("#changePwd" ).click(function () 
{
    if ($("#form_pwd").is(":show")) 
    {
    $("#form_pwd").slideDown("normal");
    }
    else
    {
    $("#form_pwd").hide();
    }
});

</script>
```

i would like to not display the form until the user click the button but I fail to make it work, it displays by default when the page shows up. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add display:none to your div

```
<div id="form_pwd" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form_pwd" ).hide();
$('#changePwd').click(function() {
  $('#form_pwd').slideToggle('slow', function() {
  });
});
</script>
```

$("#form_pwd" ).hide(); will hide your form on page load and only show once you click on change your password button.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CSS to do this

```
<div id="form_pwd" style="display:none;">
```

This will hide your div element until the click event occurs upon which jquery will slide the element down and automatically remove the display none for you

Comment: this purely not advisable... javascript being disabled, you won't see the form and therefor useless... IMO...

Comment: just use #form_pwd{display:none} .no-js #form_pwd{display:block;}, and of course add script removing .no-js from html.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do :

```
$("#form_pwd" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

what is `:show`??? I'm guessing you mean `:visible`...

use this...

```
$("#changePwd").click(function() {
    if (!$("#form_pwd").is(":visible")) {
        $("#form_pwd").slideDown("normal");
    }
    else {
        $("#form_pwd").hide();
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/Z9JmB/)

Comment: Anyway it can't work yours cause it is in a bind of a click ! so you will need to do a click to hide. Look at your code.

Comment: then one should call `$("#form_pwd").hide();`... ;)

Comment: Yeah, look at my answer just below.